# How can I 'ungroup' actions in Oro?

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I developed two actions for my 'shopping list view' page and want to display them close one to another, like this: [image: Desired behavior]

However, if I'll define them both as actions, I won't be able to ungroup them, and they will look like this:[image: Current behavior]

How can I achieve positioning of these buttons in one row?

Answer (score 1):

All action buttons defined within `shopping_list_buttons` layout container are grouped into dropdown-menu items. To have them separated, add your new button to a common parent container and define `shopping_list_buttons` as it’s sibling, something like:

```yaml
layout:
    actions:
        - ‘@add’:               
            id: move_all_to_my_cart
            siblingId: shopping_list_buttons
            parentId: product_line_item_form_buttons
            blockType: container
            prepend: true
```